# Set default to xlsm on "new" File -> Save As user interface, for specific template

Tags: excel, vba, office365, save-as

I have a Excel macro-enabled template ("template.xltm") that, when opened normally, creates a new file without a name. Users are supposed to save it as macro-enabled file with a name of their choice.

This means the first "Save As" for users should be limited to xlsm file format (filetype: 52). My current code is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If wb.Path = NullString Then

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .FilterIndex = 2
        If .Show Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        End If
    End With
```

This works if you click on the "Save" icon (the floppy disk icon) as it opens the "old" Save As interface.

It does not work when you click on **File -> Save As** that opens the "new" interface. This gives as first option *.xlsx instead of *.xlsm.

What VBA code does ALSO trigger this interface to default to Macro-enabled files?

[image: Image: New SaveAs interface with xlsx instead of xlsm]

Comment: [For reference](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4416-excel-force-save-as-macro-enabled.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this setting?

file ==> Options ==> save
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an option, as this should happen on user's computers so I have no say over their options settings

Comment: Try to use WindowDeactivate ...
`Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
... ...
End Sub
`

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below:

credit: [running vba code before save or save as](https://martinbosanacvba.blogspot.com/2021/08/running-vba-code-before-save-or-save-as.html)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If SaveAsUI or Not SaveAsUI Then
If wb.Path = NullString Then

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .FilterIndex = 2
        If .Show Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        End If
    End With
End If
End If
```

Comment: Hi Vedran, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, your addition does not trigger the BeforeSave Event. I may have to reformulate the question and ask more generally: How to trigger a BeforeSave event using the "new File->Save as interface on Windows"?